# Escaping numerals in string.replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a piece of code that uses matching groups in regular expressions to manipulate a string.

`something = mystring.replace(someRegexObject, '$1' + someotherstring);`

This code works fine in most cases however I encounter a problem when the `someotherstring` has a numeric value... then it gets concatenated with $1 messing up the group matching.

Is there an easy way for me to escape the contents of `someotherstring` to separate it from the matching group?

Comment: Supply the regex, some sample strings that cause problems and some strings that work, so that we can help you. With the current data, there's very little we can do except speculate.

Comment: Really need to know `someRegexObject` and `someotherstring`, and `mystring` because your question is like this: *"Sometimes when I use `A` and then it's not `B` when numbers are involved. "*

Comment: Are you sure this problem is with a JS regex? It usually can handle that without issues. @ctwheels The `${1}` notation will work in PHP and .NET, not in JS regex.

Comment: @ctwheels Right you are, [it is lying a lot](https://regex101.com/r/WytAxo/1). Regex101 is never a *proof* of whether a regex works or not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right, I found a different fix and posted it. I also removed my previous comments as they are incorrect for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue Explained

The question isn't the clearest, but I think I understand your issue.

Using regex in JavaScript, you can, in fact, use `$10` as a substitute for capture group 1 if - and only if - there are less than `10` groups available. See below snippet for an example of this.

```js
const regex = /(\w+)/g;
const str = `something`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, '$10');

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Unfortunately, I believe you have a regex that captures more than `X` (`10` if you're looking at the example above). See it return an incorrect value in the snippet below.

```js
const regex = /(\w+)((((((((()))))))))/g;
const str = `something`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, '$10');

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

### Solution

In order to fix this, you'll have to change your Javascript code to implement a function in the place of the substitution string as the following snippet demonstrates.

```js
const regex = /(\w+)((((((((()))))))))/g;
const str = `something`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, function(a, b) {
  return b+'0';
});

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```